# How do I delete Pushbullet

Tags: command-line

Could you tell me how to delete pushbullet via the terminal.
I can not find a way to delete the program.  Since I did not get it from the Ubuntu software list it can not allow me to delete it as with other programs.  I have not deleted anything via the terminal previously.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I did get the terminal command lines on-line.

Comment: Then it would be a good idea to post them as an answer and accept it, so that other people can see them.

Answer (score 0):

Pushbullet usually comes as a browser extension, so check your browsers and uninstall it from there.

If you installed the community project for integration right into Ubuntu, enter this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge nemo-pushbullet
```

Restart might be required (as the easiest way to remove integration in Nautilus).